# ulimit: error setting limit - Operation not permitted - (using apachectl in container on ECS)

Tags: apache, amazon-ecs

---

I see this error in my logs:

> > /usr/sbin/apachectl: 99: ulimit: error setting
> >     limit (Operation not permitted) /usr/sbin/apachectl: 99: ulimit: error
> >     setting limit (Operation not permitted)
> >
> > Setting
> >     ulimit failed. See README.Debian for more information.

First, anyone know why apache/apachectl is trying call ulimit?
Second, how can I allow this operation to work, assuming it's legit? I am calling apachectl as the root user so I don't see why this would be an issue. Although maybe apachectl runs by default as a different user than root?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have to set the ulimits in the ECS configuration like so:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3067303/how-to-configuring-linux-usage-limits-with-docker-and-aws-ecs.html

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
...
      "ulimits": [
        {
          "softLimit": 2048,
          "hardLimit": 2048,
          "name": "nofile"
        }
      ]
...
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Not working on Fargate, still having the error.